# File counting powershell vs explorer

Tags: windows, powershell

Counting files using the following script gives different answers to windows explorer?

Get-Childitem -Recurse -Attributes !Directory+!System+Encrypted -Path 'C:\Path\To\Folder' | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}

1032 Files

Windows Explorer properties

1041 Files

Why?

Comment: What about hidden attribute?

Comment: It seems your explorer is configured to show file types that you exclude in your powershell command. Check what files are not included and you will quickly have the answer.